# how to apply gradient effects when color from server

Tags: html, css

I've made a button:

```
<div class="pl-menu">

    <ul id="save-button"><li style="background-color:black" onClick="">SAVE</li></ul>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.pl-menu {

color: #FFF;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-top: 0px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
width:350px;
}

.pl-menu ul{

height:inherit;

}

 .pl-menu ul li {

list-style-type: none;
height: inherit;
text-align: center;
height: 45px;
border: 0.2px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Here is fiddle link: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/EnYe6/1/)

for some reason, I have to use this html ul and li code to make this button.

now I'd like to achieve following effects:

1)  make button looks more solid like this:

[image]

2) when user clicked the button, button looks 'fade'

[image]

Question:

a) I'd like to know, what CSS technique I can apply to make button looks more solid like image 1

b) what CSS technique I can apply to it to make it looks 'fade'. ( I tried opacity: 0.8, but it is not what I am looking for).

=======update=============

box-shadow: inset suits me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you want to make gradients but the color comes from the server, you can use an inset shadow, with a semitransparent white fading away::

```
.pl-menu ul li {

    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;

    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;

    box-shadow: inset 0px 15px 25px rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
    -webkit-animation: colors 4s infinite;
    animation: colors 4s infinite;

}
```

in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/EnYe6/9/) I have set an animation on the background color, just to show that the light effect is independent of the background color

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I have done to make your button look like the one you have in your picture.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EnYe6/8/)

1. Make the button have `padding` rather than `height` to center the text vertically and horizontally.
2. I used a gradient generated at [Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com) for the background.
3. Make the background of the whole menu black
4. Using the `:active` pseudo-element, you can assign CSS only while the object is clicked.

I set the `opacity` to `0.4` while the element is `:active`

```
.pl-menu ul li {

    list-style-type: none;
    height: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;

    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;

    background: #2b2d30; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2b2d30 0%, #45484d 28%, #000000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2b2d30), color-stop(28%,#45484d), color-stop(100%,#000000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #2b2d30 0%,#45484d 28%,#000000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #2b2d30 0%,#45484d 28%,#000000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #2b2d30 0%,#45484d 28%,#000000 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #2b2d30 0%,#45484d 28%,#000000 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2b2d30', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.pl-menu ul li:active {

    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Voila!

Comment: ha! within minutes, including the colorzilla gradient maker! :)

Comment: both of you rock...  thank you...I've learnt a lot from those.

Answer (score 1):

Question:

**a)** I'd like to know, what CSS technique I can apply to make button looks more solid like image 1

Mostly `line-height`, and a little color styling. You'll need a web font for a type face that thin.

**b)** what CSS technique I can apply to it to make it looks 'fade'. ( I tried opacity: 0.8, but it is not what I am looking for).

There are CSS3 techniques that may do it. Plain old color changes can do it too.

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2bk85/) - I made the gradients with the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

EDIT: This is very similar to @David's answer, two minutes sooner than mine. One difference is my method uses JS to set a class on the LI once clicked, presuming you want that visual state to indicate to a user that 'saving is happening'. If you don't need that and only want the effect while a person is clicking, `:active` works with less code!

Comment: Hi Will, thank you so much...I've got one more question, is it possible to make gradients only knowing a given color? the black background is dynamically retrieved from server, so just wondering, what can I do if color is dynamically retrieved ( only one color)

Comment: @robert vals explains how below